# Space Travel and Psychic Powers

Tags: story-identification

There was a series that I was reading in the 90's where certain people had various psychic powers: some were Telekinetic, others were Telepaths and so on. The government required those with these powers to wear special identification to let others know.

I can't remember many details about the series but I remember one scene early on where a Telepath was confronted by some thugs in an alley. One of the thugs noticed his ID and said something to the effect that "I only have to make you make the first move and your advantage is gone." The guy mopped the floor with them because he also had martial arts training.

I know it's a long shot but does this ring a bell for anyone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are talking about Jack Chalker's '[Quintara Marathon](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/955767.The_Demons_at_Rainbow_Bridge)' series.

Does this quote look about right?

> "Telepath, eh? You damned mind readers bleed for everybody, don't you? Well, Swami, after the first move, that little talent don't help you one bit in a fight and you know it." The thumb moved the switch back to the whip. "And all I got to do is get you to make the first move."

It's from the first book, 'The Demons at Rainbow Bridge."  Those with 'talents' had identifiers tattooed onto them; Concentric Black and White rings for Telepaths, just white rings for empaths, etc.

Comment: That's the one. Once you said the name and author it all came back. I need to pick this up and read it. Never finished the series. Only read the middle book and parts of the first one.

Comment: I had forgotten all about the references to demons in the books but it's all coming back to me now.

Comment: I also have the same problem  loaned out the books n never saw them again. Not sure if this is the correct series tho. Do they have robot teddy bears? And In suite I remember a scene of giving birth with of psychic passion control. Do you think it is the same stories? Been looking for years!

Comment: @sunshineMcGouldrick - I don't recall any robot teddy bears, but some vicious teddy bears DO factor in the later books in Chalker's better know 'Well World' series.  Perhaps you are combining a few series in your memory?

Comment: Nah thanks but the teddy wasn't evil, the toy from the movie AI is exactly from the stories. They were moving thigs like freighters, cargo ships or summin with just thought  I wish I could remember more.
. Thanks folks